# Unable to delete - Sitecore.Data.Proxies.ProxyManager missing

Tags: sitecore-rocks

I am working with Sitecore 9 and Sitecore Rocks. I successfully linked my Sitecore instance with Sitecore Rocks and can see the 3 dbs: Core Master Web, as well as the Website and Data folders.

I am currently getting an exception whenever I try to delete an item from Sitecore Rocks:

[image: Sitecore Rocks exception]

It looks to me that Sitecore 9 ProxyManager does not exist anymore and therefore it fails to delete.
Update/Create is working fine. I also tried to delete with a Sitecore 8 instance and it worked.

To get Sitecore Rocks working I had to update my web.config as mentioned [here](http://www.rockpapersitecore.com/2017/10/sitecore-rocks-with-sitecore-9/)

Anyone working with Rocks and Sitecore 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest build of Sitecore Rocks (2.1.80) which you can get here:
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/JakobChristensen/sitecore-rocks/build/artifacts

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Just tested and it worked. Any plan to include this release as part of the Visual Studio plugin?

Comment: I don't know. You could try and file an issue at his Github Repository: https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Rocks/issues